# Video carousel with small and big

Tags: javascript, carousel

I'm looking for a javascript carousel library which will work as on the picture below. 
Do you have any suggestion.

Thanks
[image: Carousel]

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using owl.carousel.js

here is the link:
http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/demos/video.html